# html/css boxed content being "annoyed" by the text supposed to be under it

Tags: html, css

I am using 3 boxes with text content where next t the the last box, some text is being displayed instead of leaving a blank and appear under.
See attached screenshot:
[image]

```css
.box_question {
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   max-width: 300px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding-bottom: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_question">
   <p class="sub-heading"> text </p>
</div>
```

float: right; does the samething but to the left...
float:center; works but doesn't not display all 3 boxes next to each others... I am not quite sure what to put between the last box and the next text. Please help me.

Comment: float doesnt have `center` mate

Comment: can you try putting it on jsfiddle?

Comment: with    float: center, the boxes appear on top of each other. Even if there is space on the right side

Comment: @LauraL. is there a property value **center** for `float` tag?

Comment: can you post more code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L9fr91ez/

Comment: Your markup is wrong too. the `p` and `div` seems to intersect each other. It should be `</p></div>` right?

Comment: Do you want it always to appear at bottom? Or it should appear on the side on smaller screens ?

Comment: </p></div>, yes. It is just a typo when posting here.

Comment: The text should always appear under even on smaller screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove **float:left** rule from .box_question selector in css.
2. enclose the text which should be displayed below the boxes inside a `<div></div>`tag.

*Tip*: If it is a responsive design consider using units like `em`, `rem` or `%` instead of `px`.

```css
.box_question {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p class="sub-heading">
  <span style="color: #000000;">Examples of Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy :</span>
</p>
<div class="box_question">
  <p class="sub-heading">Box1</p>
</div>
<div class="box_question">
  <p class="sub-heading">Box2</p>
</div>
<div class="box_question">
  <p class="sub-heading">Box3</p>
</div>
<div>
  Large text goes here which is below the boxes always...
</div>
```

Comment: This will place the boxes from a `bottom` point of  view if the boxes are not of same height

Answer (score 3):

add this text in a `p` tag and css like

```
p {
   float:left;
   width:100%;
}
```

here is the fiddle

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvLeyuj5/)

Comment: just try first then post your comment here

Comment: no problem add a class to `p` tag and you can set a width to them

Comment: is this a responsive site or normal ? are you working with responsive site dont use fixed width , that may a problem on smaller devices use `%` width

Comment: Wordpress with a custom theme. I have to add custom CSS with some plugin. Adding this class to p is not going to affect other pages?

Comment: no problem. if you add a class to this p, it will no effect other pages

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you must insert the boxes in one single `div` which will acts as a row.

i have used class: `question_row`

Then add some CSS to its `after` and `before` elements as  follows:

```css
.box_question {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:calc(50% - 150px);
}
p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.question_row::before,
.question_row::after {
  display: table;
  content: ' ';
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<p class="sub-heading"><span style="color: #000000;">Examples of Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy :</span>
</p>
<div class='question_row'>


  <div class="box_question">
    <p class="sub-heading">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box_question">
    <p class="sub-heading">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever sinn an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Itleap into electronic
      typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
      Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box_question">
    <p class="sub-heading">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
<br />Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

**EDIT:** Added `margin-left` to `.box_question` in snippet

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gvLeyuj5/1/ great! Now the boxes are not centered (when in full screen/wide resolution) with the text above and under. How can I make them appear in the middle with any screen resolution?

Comment: You can add margin-left to the boxes, I will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
try this, i think it will solve the problem
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#boxblock{
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
.box_question {
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   max-width: 300px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding-bottom: 1%;
}      
.sub-heading{
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="boxblock">
        <div class="box_question">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum, massa quam dapibus leo, eget vulputate orci purus ut lorem. In fringilla mi in ligula. Pellentesque aliquam quam vel dolor. Nunc adipiscing. Sed quam odio, tempus ac, aliquam molestie, varius ac, tellus. Vestibulum ut nulla aliquam risus rutrum interdum. Pellentesque lorem. Curabitur sit amet erat quis risus feugiat viverra. Pellentesque augue justo, sagittis et, lacinia at, venenatis non, arcu. Nunc nec libero. In cursus dictum risus. Etiam tristique nisl a nulla. Ut a orci. Curabitur dolor nunc, egestas at, accumsan at, malesuada nec, magna
        </div>
        <div class="box_question">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum, massa quam dapibus leo, eget vulputate orci purus ut lorem. In fringilla mi in ligula. Pellentesque aliquam quam vel dolor. Nunc adipiscing. Sed quam odio, tempus ac, aliquam molestie, varius ac, tellus. Vestibulum ut nulla aliquam risus rutrum interdum. Pellentesque lorem.
        </div>
        <div class="box_question">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum, massa quam dapibus leo, eget vulputate orci purus ut lorem. In fringilla mi in ligula. Pellentesque
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="sub-heading">
        <p> text </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```